# Getting unknown memory leak in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I am trying to fix the memory leak using the LeakCanary and below are the logs from the LeakCanary.
I'm new to memory leaks and not able to understand the log

HEAP ANALYSIS RESULT
====================================
1 APPLICATION LEAKS

```
    │ GC Root: System class
    │
    ├─ android.view.ViewRootImpl class
    │    Leaking: NO (MutedVideoView↓ is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
    │    ↓ static ViewRootImpl.mCastProjectionCallbacks
    ├─ java.util.ArrayList instance
    │    Leaking: NO (MutedVideoView↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ ArrayList.elementData
    ├─ java.lang.Object[] array
    │    Leaking: NO (MutedVideoView↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ Object[].[0]
    ├─ MutedVideoView instance
    │    Leaking: NO (HomeActivity↓ is not leaking and View attached)
    │    View is part of a window view hierarchy
    │    View.mAttachInfo is not null (view attached)
    │    View.mID = R.id.videoview
    │    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
    │    mContext instance of HomeActivity with mDestroyed = false
    │    ↓ MutedVideoView.mContext
    ├─ HomeActivity instance
    │    Leaking: NO (DashboardFragment↓ is not leaking and Activity#mDestroyed is false)
    │    mApplication instance of MyApplication
    │    mBase instance of io.github.inflationx.viewpump.ViewPumpContextWrapper, not wrapping known Android context
    │    ↓ HomeActivity.mDashboardFragment
    ├─ DashboardFragment instance
    │    Leaking: NO (LinearLayout↓ is not leaking and Fragment#mFragmentManager is not null)
    │    mActivityContext instance of HomeActivity with mDestroyed = false
    │    mSaveStateCallback instance of HomeActivity with mDestroyed = false
    │    ↓ DashboardFragment.mSectionContainer
    ├─ android.widget.LinearLayout instance
    │    Leaking: NO (FrameLayout↓ is not leaking and View attached)
    │    View is part of a window view hierarchy
    │    View.mAttachInfo is not null (view attached)
    │    View.mID = R.id.container
    │    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
    │    mContext instance of HomeActivity with mDestroyed = false
    │    ↓ LinearLayout.mChildren
    ├─ android.view.View[] array
    │    Leaking: NO (FrameLayout↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ View[].[3]
    ├─ android.widget.FrameLayout instance
    │    Leaking: NO (View attached)
    │    View is part of a window view hierarchy
    │    View.mAttachInfo is not null (view attached)
    │    View.mID = R.id.null
    │    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
    │    mContext instance of HomeActivity with mDestroyed = false
    │    ↓ FrameLayout.mKeyedTags
    │                  ~~~~~~~~~~
    ├─ android.util.SparseArray instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    Retaining 75819 bytes in 473 objects
    │    ↓ SparseArray.mValues
    │                  ~~~~~~~
    ├─ java.lang.Object[] array
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    Retaining 75786 bytes in 471 objects
    │    ↓ Object[].[0]
    │               ~~~
    ╰→ HomeFragment instance Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because HomeFragment received Fragment#onDestroy() callback and Fragment#mFragmentManager is null)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find solution? i am also getting same issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66514151/whats-the-best-practice-to-prevent-memory-leaks-using-datastore/66515644#66515644